# Create Google Apps Script file with DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Code to create an appscript file using appscript editor.
for example you type this:

```
     function msWordExt() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MUwH0Cm1cwHcTWSCGPp2SePbzs_4QQmtjwOEWOrOkMw');
        var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
         var get = sheetName.getRange(2,3).getValue();
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rsicZccurujGp5Ye5HUecBIAPf3_h5Pc");
        folder.createFile("PLAIN TEXT",get,MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);}
```

So the above code creates a MS Word extension file inside a persons Google Drive.

Now I want to try creating a google appscript file extension using code as well, for example the below code doesn't work but it will help give the gist of what I wish to accomplish:

```
function appScript() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MUwH0Cm1cwHcTWSCGPp2SePbzs_4QQmtjwOEWOrOkMw');
    var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
     var get = sheetName.getRange(2,3).getValue();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rsicZccurujGp5Ye5HUecBIAPf3_h5Pc");
    folder.createFile("This is an appscript file",get,MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPTS);
}
```

Comment: Hello, Adam can you please explain what is your goal? Plus, what do you mean by App Script File?

Comment: My goal is to create an appscript file using the appscript editor.  The below code creates a spreadsheet file.
function createSpreadSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("New spreadsheet");
} Now I want to be able to do the same thing for a google script file. 
function BMP() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MUwH0Cm1cwHcTWSCGPp2SePbzs_4QQmtjwOEWOrOkMw');
 var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
 var get = sheetName.getRange(2,3).getValue();
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rsicZccurujGp5Ye5HUecBIAPf3_h5Pc");
folder.createFile("working code",get,MimeType.BMP);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Considerations

You can't use the Drive API to create a Google Apps Scripts Project. [Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151165846) you can see it's already been reported to Google.

### Proposed workaround

You can use the Apps Script API to manage your Apps Script projects. Here is a link to the guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/samples/manage

### Reference

[Managing Apps Script Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects)